# Is it possible to use CORS or JSONP with the marketo rest api

Tags: cors, jsonp, marketo

I have tried to circumvent sop to get lead details from the marketo api.
Is it possible to use CORS or JSONP.
It doesn't seem to be but I fear there may be a bug in my code.

I am using the CORS method outline in the book "Third Party Javascript"

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
      console.log('We have credentials');
      xhr.open(method, url, false);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
      xhr = new XDomainRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url, false);
      console.log('Domain request is undefined');
  } else {
      xhr = null;
      console.log('null null null');    
  }

  return xhr;
};

xhr = new createCORSRequest();
xhr.open("GET", {url}, false);
xhr.send();
```

Currently I am getting the standard soap error.

Will I just have to create a new api on the domain that the document was received from. Effectively a wrapper for the Marketo rest api.

Answer (score 0):

> Will I just have to create a new api on the domain that the document was received from. Effectively a wrapper for the Marketo rest api.

This is really the best way to do it.  There might be some method you could use to circumvent it, but exposing your access token is really bad news from a security perspective.